# how to monitor outgoing HTTPS

Tags: python, linux, networking, flask

I'm using an external service to manage my users (called `stormpath`) who charges me per api call. Lately the api calls has increased greatly and I want to

log to file or to stdout all the outgoing http calls from the server (debian)

In my localhost I've done this with many hacks involving monkey patching the pips using `mitmproxy`

obviously , I can't do it in my production server.

How can I log the `https` calls and then grep only the relevant ones ?

Is there a simple plugin for flask that will do set a callback every time there is an outgoing **HTTPS request** from the Flask service outside ?

in my localhost the `mitmproxy` output looks like this

[image]

trying to get the same output using python tools in my production server .

Comment: Presumably you've written the application, so why not just put in some code to log the requests before they're made?

Comment: @JamesScholes it looks like some API calls are done with decorators and built in views provided by the `stormpath-flask` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

After checking through the [`stormpath-sdk-python`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-python) library it seems all requests goes through the [`stormpath.http.HttpExecutor`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-python/blob/master/stormpath/http.py#L141) class, specifically the [`request`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-python/blob/master/stormpath/http.py#L141) method of the `HttpExecutor` class.

[And it seems they previously had logging available for requests but chose to remove it due to problems with encoding.](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-python/commit/9926c6cd111279bea6452113233f93b0c1f1ead9)

An option would be to fork the `stormpath-sdk-python` library and add logging or a callback hook that will suit you.